# LINQ query to an array of objects

Tags: linq, highcharts

I have a Linq query that gets a set of dates and values from a database, I need to be able to push this into a HighCharts chart using JSON.

The query I've been using for my usual linqy stuff is this:

```
var data = _db.CampaignValues.GroupBy(t => t.ValueDate)
        .Select(g => new GraphValue() { T = g.Key, V = g.Sum(t => t.MessageCount) })
        .OrderBy(g => g.T)
        .Where(g => g.T > start)
        .ToArray()
;
```

For background, I'm trying to pull the data into a HighCharts "Time Data With Inrregular Intervals" chart. The data format given in their examples is:

```
data: [
    [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), 0   ],
    [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10), 0.6 ],
    [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 18), 0.7 ],
    [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  2), 0.8 ]
]
```

My problem is that I can't seem to get this into a JSON format to match the above. I either get the values quoted, or the arrays in the wrong layout.

I have tried using JsonConvert in the view, but right now I'm limited by my knowledge of JS and Linq.

```
@model IQueryable<GatorWatch.Web.Controllers.GraphValue>
@{
    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.ToList());
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    var chart1;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
            //snip
            series: [{
                type: 'line',
                name: 'Messages',
                data: [@Html.Raw(data)]
            }]
        });
    });

<script type="text/javascript">
```

But that creates a string like this:

```
data: [[
    {"T":"2013-01-02T00:00:00","V":684112},
    {"T":"2013-01-03T00:00:00","V":524172},
    {"T":"2013-01-04T00:00:00","V":769807},
    {"T":"2013-01-05T00:00:00","V":25076}
]]
```

An alternative would be using the [DotNet.Highcharts](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/) library. The example given by the library is for data to be in the form:

```
var data = new object[,]
    {
        {new DateTime(1970, 9, 27), 0},
        {new DateTime(1970, 10, 10), 0.6},
        {new DateTime(1970, 10, 18), 0.7},
        {new DateTime(1970, 11, 2), 0.8},
    }
```

---

Here's the solution I came up with the help from Alex's answer.

In the controller:

```
private static long ToJavaScriptMilliseconds(DateTime dt)
{
    long datetimeMinTimeTicks = (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).Ticks;
    return (long)((dt.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - datetimeMinTimeTicks) / 10000);
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var v1 = _db.CampaignValues.GroupBy(t => t.ValueDate)
        .Select(g => new GraphValue() { T = g.Key, V = g.Sum(t => t.MessageCount) })
        .Where(g => g.T > start)
        .OrderBy(g => g.T)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(g => new object[] { ToJavaScriptMilliseconds(g.T), g.V })
        .ToArray()
    ;

    return View(v1);

}
```

Then in the view:

```
@model object[][]

// snip 

series: [{
    type: 'line',
    name: 'Messages',
    data: @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))
}]
```

Comment: And the problem is..?

Comment: Gah, sorry, that's what happens when posting a question while getting asked other questions at work. I'll update this travesty of a question with what I've actually tried already. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project your `GraphValue` into an array of objects:

```
var data = _db.CampaignValues.GroupBy(t => t.ValueDate)
    .GroupBy(t => t.ValueDate)
    .Select(g => new GraphValue() { T = g.Key, V = g.Sum(t => t.MessageCount) })
    .Where(g => g.T > start)
    .OrderBy(g => g.T)
    .Select(g => new object[] { g.T,  g.V })
    .ToArray();
```

A note: there is no sense in ordering, and then filtering the same data. It's better to filter first, and order less data then.

Comment: That's pretty much it I think. All I need to do now is work out how to get the JavaScript time from a DateTime, but I think Google will help me there.

Comment: You can use var time = new Date()